# Why do Chinese people say 一孕傻三年？

Tags: meaning

Just the other day, I heard this '一孕傻三年'. Does anyone have an inkling as to why Chinese people think this?

Comment: http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%AD%95%E5%82%BB
民间俗称“一孕傻三年”，意思是当女性怀孕后，准妈咪的记忆力会有衰退的迹象，常常会丢三落四，而且有研究发现当女性怀孕后的确有可能出现记忆力衰退和认知能力下降等问题，通常我们叫此为“孕傻”或“婴儿脑”状态。

Comment: Seems that this concept is also alive and kicking in the west: "Motherhood is Making Me Stupid - Scary Mommy", "Why do pregnancy hormones make you so stupid ...", "Why do i feel stupid after having my baby? | Yahoo Answers", "Does pregnancy make women stupid?! -RANT- - Hot Topics ..."

Comment: I never knew that! You learn something every day! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment

It's not only in Chinese culture, it's called "baby brain" http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/pregnancy-week-by-week/expert-answers/baby-brain/faq-20057896

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion ,孕傻三年 because mothers takes more attention on their baby , so they are seeming stupid and forgetful.

Answer (score 1):

It means that pregnancy makes a woman sutpid and forgetful. In western culture, there is an equivalnent words "baby brain" which means the pregancy or early motherhood can harm a woman's memory and ability to think. As a local Chinese han bridge teacher, many of my colleagues who give birth to baby often told me “一孕傻三年” when they forget something and do something in wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Even though baby brain or "momnesia" is often reported by pregnant women, [webMD](http://www.webmd.com/baby/features/memory_lapse_it_may_be_pregnancy_brain) states: "Pregnancy does not change a woman's brain even though some women don't feel as sharp as usual when they're pregnant."
Even [this news article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-3029080/Baby-brain-DOESN-T-exist-Tests-reveal-pregnant-women-new-mothers-suffer-no-decline-leading-scientists-declare-condition-mind.html) says US researchers claim "momnesia" is a sort of made-up excuse for common forgetfulness. You can read them more since it seems to give other reasons why baby brain actually occurs.

In any case, I've been living in China for 5 years and have heard that Chinese phrase come up around pregnant Chinese mothers. Right now I'm visiting my family in the US, and every time my brother's pregnant wife randomly tweaks out over forgetting something or being slow, I remember what those Chinese said and I blurt out 一孕傻三年. I think she's just under lots of stress and bodily changes, and stress can cause lots of problems on its own.